# Select field names assigning an alias in firebird

Tags: firebird

It is possible to assign a alias to each fields when doing a select of field names, like that:

```sql
select rdb$field_name as field 
from rdb$relation_fields 
where rdb$relation_name='TableName'
```

What, for instance, would return something like that:

```
FieldName1
FieldName2
FieldName3
```

I'm looking for a way of set an alias for each field, instead returning FieldName1 return MyName, so on.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with assign an alias? What would you use that alias for?

Comment: The same way when doing a select field_table as "My field name" I want to do with the name of the fields of a table and show to user that name.

Comment: there is no point for a user to ever look directly into system tables

Answer (score 1):

You may run command `comment on column tablename.tablecolumn is 'my comment text'`

See chapter 5.16 in [SQL manual](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-comment-create)

But then you would have to do a special query to fetch comments along with field names.

```
select coalesce(rdb$description, rdb$field_name) as field 
from rdb$relation_fields 
where rdb$relation_name='TableName'
```